# My event listener activates all elements below. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js

```
    initAccordion(){
  const thisProduct = this;
  const clickTrigger = document.querySelectorAll(select.menuProduct.clickable);

    for (let click of clickTrigger) {
      click.addEventListener('click', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('click');
        thisProduct.element.classList.toggle(classNames.menuProduct.wrapperActive);

        const allActiveProducts = document.querySelectorAll(classNames.menuProduct.wrapperActive);

        for(let active of allActiveProducts){
          if (active !== thisProduct) {
            active.classList.remove(classNames.menuProduct.wrapperActive);
          }
        }
      });
    }
}
```

When event is triggerd on one generated element all elements below are getting class active. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Providing a runnable [mcve] would sure be helpful. Click on `<>` in question editor to create such a demo right here in the page

Comment: use event bubbling, attach event handler to parent element & find the target element by id/class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
event.stopPropagation();
```

Add this after `event.preventDefault()`, it will allow only one selector(which comes first or where you click) to trigger, not all.